# How can I make the legend items bigger with react-plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using react-plotly.js and I have a graph with some dots with a color and a border. I want the border to be thick, the problem is that it looks bad in the legend, because the legend is so small.

Is there a way to either remove the border from the legend, or increase the size of the dots on the legend?

viewed on the graph:
[image: on the graph]

how it shows on the legend:
[image: legend]

Similar issue someone had, can't resize items only text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```py
fig.update_layout(legend_itemsizing="constant")
```

> [`itemsizing`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend-itemsizing) - Determines if the legend items symbols scale with their corresponding "trace" attributes or remain "constant" independent of the symbol size on the graph.

In general, we set `itemsizing="constant"` if the marker size is a variable and `itemsizing="trace"` if the marker size is fixed, but in your situation when the marker size is fixed to a small value which is too small for the legend, the "constant" sizing probably remains the best option.

However, this constant is hardcoded somewhere and we can't override it, so the resulting size in the legend might not suffice. The only other way ("trace") sadly requires to increase the marker size on the traces.

Comment: How do I set the size after saying it's constant?

Comment: I precisely mentioned "_this constant is hardcoded somewhere and we can't override it, so the resulting size in the legend might not suffice. The only other way ("trace") sadly requires to increase the marker size on the traces."

Comment: So, what does it mean? How setting it to constant helps? I'm confused

Comment: When the legend itemsizing is set to "trace", then the markers in the legend have the same size as those on the traces. In your screenshot, the marker size on the traces appears to be (fixed and) relatively small, setting itemsizing to "constant" in this case is the best option as it provides a constant minimal size, which might not be sufficient of course, and we can't set that constant value so it's not perfect, but from what I've tried at least it will still be larger than the size you got currently on the screenshot.